Running multiple ICCs on one dataframe in R
I'm trying to calculate multiple ICCs from a data frame created in R. The data frame contains over 2500 observations from 122 different persons. I need an ICC calculated for each person.
Creating a separate data frame for one person, I am able to calculate the ICC using the package irr in R:
data_edue_icc_212003 <- subset(data_edue, vp_id == 212003 , 
                        select = c(stress_sad : stress_tense))

icc(data_edue_icc_212003,
    model = "twoway",
    type = "agreement",
    unit = "single")

These are the results:
Single Score Intraclass Correlation

   Model: twoway 
   Type : agreement 

   Subjects = 19 
     Raters = 9 
   ICC(A,1) = 0.214

 F-Test, H0: r0 = 0 ; H1: r0 > 0 
 F(18,89.3) = 4.37 , p = 1.35e-06 

 95%-Confidence Interval for ICC Population Values:
  0.095 < ICC < 0.42

Instead of having to subset the data frame 122 times to isolate the data for one person, I want to apply ICC by row, grouping the data frame by ID.
I guess there is a quicker way to calculate ICCs all at once than calculating 122 ICCs on separate data frames. What I'm looking for is an output that could look like this:
Test    ICC
 ID1   (icc value)
 ID2   (icc value)
...


Use map_dfr from purrr. Essentially, we just loop through the unique values of the vp_id variable and run your code using each value one by one. The output is a data frame with the two columns as required.
map_dfr(unique(data_edue$vp_id), \(id)
       list(Test=id, ICC=icc(subset(data_edue, vp_id==id,
                                 select = stress_sad:stress_tense),
                             model = "twoway",
                             type = "agreement",
                             unit = "single")$value))


# A tibble: 3 x 2
    Test     ICC
   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 212001 -0.0217
2 212002 -0.0619
3 212003 -0.122 


Data:
data_edue <- data.frame(vp_id=c(212001, 212002, 212003),
                        stress_sad=runif(57, 50, 100),
                        stress_nervous=runif(57, 50, 100),
                        stress_worried=runif(57, 50, 100),
                        stress_anxious=runif(57, 50, 100),
                        stress_tense=runif(57, 50, 100))

libraries:
library(irr)
library(purrr)

